# Insert section to UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to add a new section programmatically to UITableview?

I have pagination and when I try call insertSections in performBatchUpdates it works fine for the first time but when load second page UITableview does't update (no errors just not updated and do not called completion block).

```
private var periods = [PeriodHistoryModel]()

func fetchHistoryWith(models: [PeriodHistoryModel]) {
    guard models.count > 0 else {
        return
    }

    let newSectionsCount = models.count - periods.count
    let lastPeriod = periods.count - 1 >= 0 ? periods.count - 1 : 0

    var newRows: [IndexPath] = [IndexPath]()
    var newSections: [IndexSet] = [IndexSet]()

    let lastPeriodOldCount = periods.last?.sessions.count ?? 0
    let lastPeriodNewCount = models[lastPeriod].sessions.count
    let newSessionsCount = lastPeriodNewCount - lastPeriodOldCount

    if lastPeriod >= 0 {>
        for index in 0..<newSessionsCount {
            newRows.append(IndexPath(row: lastPeriodOldCount + index, section: lastPeriod))
        }
    }
    for index in 0..<newSectionsCount {
        let newSectionIndex = periods.count + index
        newSections.append(IndexSet(integer: newSectionIndex))
        for rowIndex in 0..<models[newSectionIndex].sessions.count {
            newRows.append(IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: newSectionIndex))
        }
    }

    periods = models

    tableView.performBatchUpdates({
        for index in 0..<newSections.count {
            tableView.insertSections(newSections[index], with: .none)
        }
        tableView.insertRows(at: newRows, with: .none)
    })
}
```

reloadData does not fit need to do it smoothly

Comment: I dont see where you are updating the table data when you reload?

Comment: I call performBatchUpdates

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in your numberOfSections func, do you get the correct number of sections when you update?

Answer (score 4):

The rule of thump is "update table view models before performing batch updates". I just created a simple project and it works fine. So Make sure your delegate method numberOfSections return the updated model's count.

My project below.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var numberOfSections: Int = 1
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func insertSectionTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        numberOfSections += 1
        let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: numberOfSections - 1)
        tableView.performBatchUpdates({
            tableView.insertSections(indexSet, with: .none)
        }) { (update) in
            print("Update SUccess")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func insertRowTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return numberOfSections
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "DefaultId")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "This is Section \(indexPath.section) - Row \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: private var periods = [PeriodHistoryModel]()  I build sections based on this array

Comment: Can I ask you a question related to add Section in tableView?