# Separators in table views(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

How can I add these separators or blank spaces between the tableview cells?

Or you just use two different cells?

[image]

Comment: where are you want these spaces, between section or between cells ?

Comment: You're seeing a "grouped" table (instead of a "plain" table). Look at the `UITableView.style` property or you can change it through the story board editor

Comment: You can divide table in section. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058233/insert-section-to-uitableview help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add section footer view

Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    return footerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```